# How to build and use the C++ API for Tensorflow on windows

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel

Has anyone been successful in building/using the c++ API for TensorFlow on windows (withing Visual Studio)? The tutorials I found online or on TensorFlow's website have only shown building from source for python, or are outdated (3+ years old or for TensorFlow 1.x)

I see that there are docs for the functions of the built C++ API on TensorFlow's website, but there's no mention of where to get it or how to build it, the build from source section builds the python package that can be installed using pip, not anything that can be used with C++.

I've looked at the C api, but that seems to be different from what is mentioned in the C++ API section of the docs, and I was unable to get the C API working within VS due an error in mixing C++ and C.

If it helps, the end goal is to run inferences for pre-trained models (built using the python API) using C++.

Any help is appreciated.